# QScrollBar stylesheet resize handle

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I need to style some scrollbars as in the image:

[image]

After much pain and experimentation, I found how to make the gradient, and hide the arrows.

```
m_scrollBarStyleSheet = "QScrollBar:horizontal { \n "
                "  background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 1, y1: 0.5, x2: 0, y2: 0.5, stop: 0 magenta, stop: 1 #FFFFFF); \n "
                "  border: 1px solid black; \n"
                "  height: 35px; \n "
                "  width: 261px; \n"
                "  margin: 0 0 0 0; \n "
                "} \n "
                "QScrollBar::handle:horizontal { \n"
                "  background-color: silver; \n"
                "  border: 1px solid grey; \n"
                "  height: 55px; \n" // seems to do nothing
                "  width: 2px; \n"   // seems to do nothing
                "} \n"
                "QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal { \n" // hides arows
                "  border: none; background: none; \n"
                "} \n"
                "QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal { \n" // makes background show through
                "  border: none; \n"
                "} \n";

QString s = m_scrollBarStyleSheet;
s.replace("magenta", "yellow"); // whatever color I need
horizontalScrollBar->setStyleSheet(s);
...
```

The result: close enough:

[image]

But nothing I do seems to allow me to resize the actual scrolling piece (handle ?) - I can't make it thinner, and I have not seen anything that can make its height exceed the height of the rectangle behind.

How can I size the little sliding rectangle to fit, as much as possible, the required image ?

Note I must use Qt 4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that `QScrollBar` handle width cannot be changed, it is calculated as a percentage of the bar.

So, I replaced the scroll bar with a slider, which is also capable of having a handle height exceed the total width of the bar: by setting a negative margin.

(I used this [example](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2010/03/10/fancy-qslider-stylesheet/) to update the style from my question).